# CSS: Prevent wrap between spans

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have the following html-code:

```
<span class="product">
    My really super product
</span>
<span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
```

My problem is that sometimes the text is wrapped before €, so I get:

```
My really super product 19,99
€
```

I would prefer:

```
My really super product 
19,99 €
```

The problem is: I only could add an additional tag arround this code but couldn't change the code itself (because it's generated by a 3rd-party-tool). Okay, it would be possible somehow replaceing the output, but the real code is more complicated than this example.

So is it possible to prevent the wrap between price and currency only by CSS?

Added: Sorry, I forgot to mention. It should be possible to get

```
My really super product 19,99 €
```

in one line as well if there is enough space in width.

Comment: Is this a multi currency application? If not, CSS only is possible.

Comment: have you tried display:block for first span

Comment: `.product {display:block}` In this way the other span go on a new line

Comment: Thanks for your replys. The problem is that "My really super product 19,99
€" should be possible in one line as well.

Comment: then please use media query to add display:block

Comment: Yes, the currency might change.

Comment: Using media query: interesting idea. But I don't know how long the product-name will be (might be "My really super product in red with additional something in blue" as well).

Comment: Simply change to `<span class="currency">&nbsp;€</span>` and it will wrap how you want. The `&nbsp;` will create a space though prevent it from breaking into a new line.

Comment: Or drop the space in the `currency` span and add one using a pseudo element, e.g. `.currency::before {
  content:"\00a0";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will suit

**Variant 1**

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .price {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .currency {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper" style="width: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper" style="width: 155px; background-color: #0f0;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper" style="width: 140px; background-color: #99f;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>
```

Here `.wrapper` is not really necessary. In most cases you may add the style just for `.price` and `.currency`. Try to inject the solution into you layout and review.

**Variant 2**

```css
.price {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.currency {
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div style="width: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div style="width: 155px; background-color: #0f0;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper" style="width: 140px; background-color: #99f;">
    <span class="product">
        My really super product
    </span>
    <span class="price">19,99</span><span class="currency"> €</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the wrapper and absolute positioning, and use these 2 rules `.currency {
  margin-left: -1em;
}
.price {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
` ... with `em` it will work much better with different font sizes, which `px` won't

Answer (score -2):

U have to use `<br/>` may this will help you to add the data like that

```
<span=class="">
 My really super product</Span><br/>
<spa="">19,99</span><span="">$</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that "My really super product 19,99
€" should be possible in one line as well.

Comment: put that in div